# CSS image over JS animated image

Tags: css

I created following simple website. I have Starfield and galaxy pictures. Starfield is animated by JS code. Stars are moving. But when I place Galaxy over starfield with CSS code stars stop moving.
Below I placed JS code and HTML code without placing galaxy over starfield. How can I place one over another with stars moving?

Regards
Piotr

```
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8">
  <title> Galaktyka</title>

  <script src ="Code17.js"></script>

  <style>       
    #galaxy{
      display: block;
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }      
    #star{
      position: relative;
    }        
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    window.onscroll = function () {
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>

  <img id="galaxy" src="Galaktyka.jpg" style="width: 70%">
  <img id="star" src="starfield.jpg">
</body>
```

And below JS

```
window.onload = function(){
  let image =  document.getElementById("star");
  imageLeft = -175;
  setInterval(move, 100, image);
}

var motion = true;

function move() {
  if(motion) {
    let image =  document.getElementById("star");
    imageLeft = imageLeft + 1;
    image.style.left = imageLeft + "px";

    if (imageLeft == 0) {
      motion = false;
    } else {
      let image =  document.getElementById("star");
      imageLeft = imageLeft - 1;
      image.style.left = imageLeft + "px";
    }

    if (imageLeft == -175){
      motion = true; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For a better understanding, can you post a code sandbox for it? 
https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Hi
Something like this?
https://codesandbox.io/s/webpage-veuwl?file=/index.html